# Needs to clean-up stale data from DynamoDB table which is older than 90 days by keeping cost as low as possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, analytics

Use Case: Cleanup old telemetry data from very Big DynamoDb table based on timestamp which is older then 90 days

Date Size: 750 GB ( Ireland + Ohio + Beijing )

Item Count : 5000 million records

Sample Data:

```
{
    "deviceid": "a00a940c-b804-4806-a14f-7c713964fc65",
    "timestamp": 1661521317,
    "notifications": false,
    "payload": [
      {
        "n": "temprature",
        "v": "20"
      },
      {
        "n": "humidity",
        "v": "91"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Goal: Needs to clean-up stale data from DynamoDB table which is older than 90 days by keeping cost as low as possible

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB has a TTL feature to delete items based on a timestamp value field in your item.
Enable it on your table with the timestamp column for the specific duration you need

TTL is free and doesn't consume your write throughput as well.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html